# Timezone in python date string is not matching

Tags: python, python-3.x, date

In a script, I am converting the date string into DateTime format, so that I can modify the date, but this timezone part is showing an error.

```
from datetime import datetime
date_str = 'Wed, 1 Jun 2022 16:44:40 +0200 (CEST)'

temp_date = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z (%Z)')
print(temp_date)
```

When I run this I am getting ValueEror.

```
ValueError: time data 'Wed, 01 Jun 2022 16:44:40 +0200 (CEST)' does not match format '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z (%Z)'
```

Comment: what version are you on? works fine for me on python 3.9

Comment: Python 3.10.4 @BijayRegmi

Comment: Even tried an online compiler https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/

Comment: @BijayRegmi did you copy-paste the complete code and try? I am still getting errors on other online compilers as well.

Comment: I did and looking at Gaziz's answer, it makes sense as I am from CEST timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing the complexity of problem, I suggest using third party library like `dateutil` which can parse datetime with ease.

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
date_str = 'Wed, 1 Jun 2022 16:44:40 +0200 (CEST)'
temp_date = parse(date_str)
print(temp_date)
```

`temp_date` is of type `datetime.datetime`

https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: Thank you. This not only solved this problem but also helped me with another scenario. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

An extract from the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) documentation:

> strptime() only accepts certain values for %Z:
>
> any value in time.tzname for your machine’s locale
>
> the hard-coded values UTC and GMT
>
> So someone living in Japan may have JST, UTC, and GMT as valid values,
> but probably not EST. It will raise ValueError for invalid values

Try running the below to see if CEST is in your machine's locale:

```
import time
print(time.tzname)
```

Comment: Only ('IST', 'IST'). Then how can I handle this? Any idea?